# can 3 legged oauth static callback url be converted to dynamic url without severe security repercussions?

Tags: web-services, redirect, github, oauth, oauth-2.0

github 3 legged oauth authentication requires defining the callback url (or at least the host) while creating the github application. that means the url is static.

we have several deployments for our site, and each deployment has a different host, so we needed a github application for each deployment - which is annoying to maintain.

now we've started dynamically generating deployment hosts/ports and can no longer have a github application per deployment.

we need the oauth callback url to be dynamic so that we'll be able to specify the dynamically generated host/port.

we thought about creating a second party webservice somewhere that will redirect the oauth-callback:

- when you create the github application, you assign the redirect webservice url.
- when authenticating you pass the url of the host trying to authenticate to github as a paramter
- github queries the auth callback on the redirect service which retrieves the original_host_url parameter and redirects there, thus reaching the relevant webservice url, dynamically.

so 2 questions:

- will this solution work and solve my issue, technically speaking?
- does this introduce security issues, other than having the redirect service use https and maybe accept connections only from oauth providers such as github?

Comment: there seems to be something called an open redirect exploit this might enable: http://dannythorpe.com/2014/05/02/tech-analysis-of-serious-security-flaw-in-oauth-openid-discovered/